# Should my question be migrated to Super User or not?

Tags: support, migration

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87068/where-to-find-sleep-mode-drivers-for-debian-distro). Should it be migrated to this site since it's about drivers and hardware or should it stay on unix.stackexchange.com?

I didn't know where to ask it, I picked a place randomly.

Comment: It's entirely up to you but the question it self is vague.  You don't indicate the exact GPU you have not have you indicated if installing the Nvidia/AMD drivers worked for you

Comment: @Ramhound I'll add all the details needed tomorrow, thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply looking at the topic "Linux", your question would be fine for both [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and Super User.

There is a certain overlap between these sites, and it you are free to choose where to ask. People regularly get confused over the existence of two or more sites where they can ask about, say, Ubuntu. There are no rules on where to post, except that you shouldn't post your question to multiple sites simultaneously.

That being said, as @Ramhound pointed out, you might want to add some more details to your post, such as the hardware specifications, what exact drivers you tried, et cetera.

Finally, if your question does not get much attention within a couple of days, or no good response at all, you may have it migrated here. Just flag it for attention over on unix.SE.

Comment: I'll add all the details needed tomorrow, thank you sir, I've never tried flagging a question before, will do that in a couple of days, thank you